# JES image duplicating

Tags: python, jes

I am working on a project where I need to print any image selected by the user a number of times selected by the user too.

My code is mostly working but I need to make a nested loop that will basically change the values for the Xpos and Ypos of the original image and change it to make the new picture.

```
def repeat(pic):
    val = requestIntegerInRange("Enter 1-10", 1, 10)
    print "The user entered :" + str(val)
    w = getWidth(pic)
    h = getHeight(pic)
    print "Height and Width of this image are:", h, w
    result = makeEmptyPicture(w, h * val)
    xpos = 0
    while(xpos < w):
        ypos = 0
        while(ypos < h):
            pixel = getPixel(pic, xpos, ypos)
            color = getColor(pixel)
            loop = 0
            while(loop <= val):
                newX = xpos
                newY = ypos + h * val
                pixel2 = getPixel(result, newX, newY)
                setColor(pixel2, color)
                loop = loop + 1
            ypos = ypos + 1
        xpos = xpos + 1
```

Here `val` is the value selected by the user to print the image a number of times.

When I run my program with the above code it shows

```
The error value is: 
Inappropriate argument value (of correct type).Height and Width of the Picture are : 208 146
getPixel(picture,x,y): y (= 1456) is less than 0 or bigger than the height (= 1455)
An error occurred attempting to pass an argument to a function.
```

Comment: You are trying to pick a pixel outside of your image `result`. (That's just to be clear about what the error tells you). Check your logic around newY computation.

Comment: I made a loop loop=0
    while(loop<=val):
      newX = xpos
      newY = ypos + h
      pixel2=getPixel(result,newX,newY)
      setColor(pixel2,color)
      loop=loop+1    
still not able to figure out this. Im sure im making some mistake in my logic but im not able to figure it out

Comment: You should post more of your code, we a missing context here.

Comment: def repeat(pic):

  val = requestIntegerInRange("Enter 1-10",1,10)
  print "The user entered :"+str(val)
  w = getWidth(pic)
  h = getHeight(pic)
  
  print "Height and Width of this image are:",h,w
  
  
  result = makeEmptyPicture(w,h*val)
  
  xpos=0
  while(xpos<w):
   ypos=0
   while(ypos<h):
    
    pixel = getPixel(pic,xpos,ypos)
    color = getColor(pixel)
    
    loop=0
    while(loop<=val):
      newX = xpos
      newY = ypos + h
      pixel2=getPixel(result,newX,newY)
      setColor(pixel2,color)
    loop=loop+1
     
    ypos=ypos+1
   xpos=xpos+1

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `newY = ypos + h * val` where it should be `newY = ypos + h * loop`.

Moreover your loop on val should stop on `loop < val` not `loop <= val`. The last copy is unwanted (it's the (val + 1)th) and that's the part that makes you program fail I think.